# For Each Parent How Many Children of specific item?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm having issues understanding conceptually how to loop through this array to create 2 variables. One includes the Parents[symbols] and the other includes how many children dates[dates] exist for that symbol.

```
 'AMLP' => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2432' (length=4)
      'symbol' => string '.AMLP' (length=14)
      'dates' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2019-09-13' (length=10)
  'ARCC' => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2417' (length=4)
      'symbol' => string '.ARCC' (length=14)
      'dates' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2019-09-13' (length=10)
          1 => string '2019-09-13' (length=10)
          2 => string '2019-09-10' (length=10)
          3 => string '2019-09-10' (length=10)
```

I'm trying to create 2 sets of data and print them to look exactly like this :

```
[AMPL,ARCC]
[1,4]
```

Comment: since I can't submit a one-character edit, I think "AMPL" in the second-last line is a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = [
    
    "AMLP" => [
        "id" => "2432",
        "symbol" => "AMLP",
        "dates" => ["2019-09-13"]
    ],
    
    "ARCC" => [
        "id" => "2417",
        "symbol" => "ARCC",
        "dates" => ["2019-09-13", "2019-09-13", "2019-09-10", "2019-09-10"]
    ]
];

$counts = [];
foreach($array as $key => $arr){
    $counts[$key] = count($arr["dates"]);
}
var_dump($counts);
```

$counts will be looking like this

```
// $count = ["AMLP" => 1 , "ARCC" => 4];
```

Live Demo https://3v4l.org/Titkv

#### Edit:

If you want exactly this string `[AMLP,ARCC]` you can do something like this

```
echo "[" . implode(",", array_keys($counts)) . "]";
echo "[" . implode(",", $counts) . "]";
//prints
//[AMLP,ARCC]
//[1,4]
```

Comment: I think I had this before, but as far as printing it out as two variables. That for some reason I'm blanking on.

Comment: Do you need exactly the same string `"[AMLP,ARCC]"` ? OK I will update the answer a little

Comment: Yes correct. One for each.Is it appending to create separate varaibles?

Answer (score 1):

Formally speaking you can use this code:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$counts = [];
foreach($array as $arr){
    $counts[] = count($arr["dates"]);
}
```

But it's better to store the relation between code and count. That's why another answer is more suitable.